# Name, caption and id in icCube

Tags: iccube

In Mondrian all cubes, measures, dimensions, hierarchies, levels, properties have two identifiers: a unique name, for schema definition and a caption, displayed to the user, which may not be unique.

I am wondering if the same concept is in the distinction between id and name attributes of the dimension tag in icc-schema xml?

I did not found anything similar for hierarchy, level and properties. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the dimension XML definition:

"**id**" is used internally by icCube to link facts to dimensions.

"**name**" is what being displayed to the end user and is used in MDX to identify the dimension within a query.

Hierarchies and levels are used differently so there is no such needs.

Hope that helps.